# How to set different background-color to rows dinamically in Gijgo Grid?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, grid

I'm using a Gijgo grid to manage data of a table.

I would to set background color of different rows. The colors are in the model.

**View**

```
       grid = $("#grid").grid({
        dataSource: { url: '@Url.Action("Method", "MyController")', success: onSuccessFunc },
        dataKey: "Id",
        uiLibrary: "bootstrap",
        columns:
        [
            { field: "Id", sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "Name", sortable: false, hidden: true },
            { field: "Description", title: "Tipologia", sortable: false, width: "70%" },
            { field: "Value1", title: "Value 1", align: 'center', sortable: false },
            { field: "Value2", title: "Value 2", align: 'center', sortable: false },
            { field: "Edit", title: "", width: 34, type: "icon", icon: "glyphicon-pencil", tooltip: "Edit", events: { "click": Edit } }
        ]
    });
```

**ViewModel**

```
public class ViewModel
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public string Name { get; set; }
    public string Description { get; set; }
    public double? Value1 { get; set; }
    public double? Value2 { get; set; }
    public string Group { get; set; }
    public string BackGroudColor { get; set; }
}
```

How can I do to bind a property background-color of a row of the grid to  backgroundcolor property  of the model?

Thank you very much.

Charles

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The best option would be to use the rowDataBound event of the gijgo grid.
You can read more about this event at http://gijgo.com/Grid/Events/rowDataBound

Example 1:

```
grid.on('rowDataBound', function (e, $row, id, record) {
    $row.css('background-color', id%2 === 0 ? '#FFFFFF' : '#CCCCCC');
});
```

Example 2:

```
grid.on('rowDataBound', function (e, $row, id, record) {
    if (record.Name === 'something') {
        $row.css('background-color',  '#CCCCCC');
    }
});
```

Comment: Great Atanas...Thank you